# Getting network location in background in ANDROID

Tags: android, location, broadcastreceiver

I am researched from many threads here for getting location information in Android OS, and tried few designs. However, I was getting lots of battery drain everytime, just couldn't get rid of it. Here is a part of my code.

LocationReceiver.Java

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static double latestUpdate = 0;
public static int status = 0;
public static int count_upload = 0;
public static int count_ignored = 0;
public static Geocoder gc;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Do this when the system sends the intent
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    Location loc = (Location) b
            .get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    if (loc == null)
        return;
    if (gc == null)
        gc = new Geocoder(context);
    update(loc, context);
}

public void update(Location loc, Context context) {
    // Here I am checking if 10 minutes passed from last update to now.
    // and if so, I am uploading my location to my server.
    if (latestUpdate != 0
            && latestUpdate + ((LaunchReceiver.interval - 2) * 1000) > SystemClock
                    .elapsedRealtime()) {
        // duplicate (ignore)
        count_ignored++;
    } else {
        // Upload to server on an async task.
        // ...
        LocationReceiver.latestUpdate = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        count_upload++;
    }

}
}
```

LaunchReceiver.Java

```
public class LaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static boolean registered = false;
public static LocationManager lm;
public static int interval = 600000;
public static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (registered)
        return;
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    interval = Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("updates_interval",
            "600000"));
    Intent in = new Intent("bdd.sanalmusavir.LOCATION_READY");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    lm = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Register for broadcast intents
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, interval,
            0, pendingIntent);

    registered = true;
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.Xml

```
<application
    <receiver
        android:name=".LaunchReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="bdd.sanalmusavir.LOCATION_READY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Of course, this is just part of my code. I tried before same thing with a service by adding alarms periodically but that was draining battery as well.

In this practice, let's say I set the interval to 10 minutes, and when I register location updates (requestLocationUpdates), I am getting location updates random intervals (every 30 seconds or so). How can I get rid of it? What is wrong with checking if 10 minutes passed and uploading to server if so?

When I check count_ignored and count_uploaded after 1 day, ignored count was 2100~ and uploaded count was 50~ (upload count was true). And my application was used 90 minutes of CPU, which was unacceptable. (Upload part of application is just calling an URL on the web, with HttpRequest).

How can I implement better design? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The field minInterval on LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates takes a millisecond time. You are passing 600 which will cause the manager to fire every 600ms or basically as fast as it can. I think you're just missing a *1000 in there.

Comment: It was just for test purpose. Sorry forgot to mention it on my post. I am using it from my preferences which is 600 * 1000. Fixed my post.